# Can I say it this way " People are benefited by social networking "

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it correct to say

> People are benefited by Social Networking

when what I really want to say is that

> People benefit from Social Networking

Comment: People are benefiting from Social Networking.

Comment: If you have specific examples you are going to cite, you could say "People have benefited from Social Networking".

Comment: It may be correct, but is it **true**?

Answer (score 1):

It's not *incorrect* if you're going for passive voice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice

However, you should use whichever makes the most sense in your context. I would argue that the active voice sounds better here. Maybe also consider: "Social networking benefits people."

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> People benefit from Social Networking.
>
> Social Networking [caters](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cater) to people.

Answer (score -1):

People are benefited from social networking.

"by" would not be used in the first sentence. benefited is not an adjective. fist sentence of questioner is ungrammatical.

Second sentence is correct to say.