# Is it grammatical to say "A can be benefit from B"?

Tags: grammar

I have seen several times of "A can be benefit from B".
But my teacher told me that benefit can only be a noun here.
Thus, the sentence is not correct.

After googling, I get lots of results about "A can be benefit from B".
I am confused now. Is the sentence grammatical or ungrammatical?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related, [Can I say it this way “ People are benefited by social networking”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165916/can-i-say-it-this-way-people-are-benefited-by-social-networking/165925#165925)

Comment: @Rathony, thx. But my question is about parts of speech and phrase, and the suggested one is more about active/passive voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is correct. I believe you meant to say "A can benefit from B."

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not correct, but your teacher (if that is exactly what he said) is not correct either. The are several grammatical sentences possible here: 'A can be a benefit for B', 'A can be a benefit from B', 'A can benefit from B', or 'A can be benefitted by B' [though I would not use *from* here, some people would]. *Benefit* is a noun in the first two, but a verb in the others.  Note also that the four meanings are distinct.

'A can be benefit from B', as a sentence, is not grammatical;  I suspect that the uses you have found are sub-clauses, or possibly just early drafts.